# Login to SSL VPN via SSO and then use SSO inside VPN for other Service Providers possible?

Tags: vpn, single-sign-on, session, authorization, saml

I have a setup where you authorize via SAML SSO (keycloak as idp) to access a SSL VPN (fortigate as sp). Now inside the VPN there are authorization reverse proxy servers.

Is it possible to have the same SSO automatically authorize users to the proxy servers?

Since the session of a user is saved with the IP before accessing the VPN I would think the session isn't valid after connecting to it because it has now a different IP?

Comment: depending on the used software...?

Comment: The software doesn't matter for me right now. As long as it is possible in general. I don't know how sessions work and I don't want a client to login twice with the same credentials. Is there a keyword that will help me with this? Or is it just not possible to practically do this?